# Matrix multiplication in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I have two Mat images in OpenCV:

```
Mat ft = Mat::zeros(src.rows,src.cols,CV_32FC1);
Mat h = Mat::zeros(src.rows,src.cols,CV_32FC1);
```

Both images are the same dimension and are calculated from a single source image.

I would like to multiply these two images but have tried using both

```
Mat multiply1 = h*ft;

Mat multiply2;
gemm(h,ft,1,NULL,0,multiply2);
```

but both result in the following assertion failure:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (a_size.width == len) in unknown function, file ...matmul.cpp
>   Termination called after throwing 'cv::exception'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To see what the exception actually _says_, put the failing line inside a `try` block like:  `try { [...] } catch (cv::Exception const & e) { std::cerr<<"OpenCV exception: "<<e.what()<<std::endl; }`

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You say that the matrices are the same dimensions, and yet you are trying to perform matrix multiplication on them. Multiplication of matrices with the same dimension is only possible if they are square. In your case, you get an assertion error, because the dimensions are not square. You have to be careful when multiplying matrices, as there are two possible meanings of multiply.

**[Matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29)** is where two matrices are multiplied directly. This operation multiplies matrix A of size [a × b] with matrix B of size [b × c] to produce matrix C of size [a × c]. In OpenCV it is achieved using the simple `*` operator:

```
C = A * B
```

**[Element-wise multiplication](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a385c09827713dc3e6d713bfad8460706)** is where each pixel in the output matrix is formed by multiplying that pixel in matrix A by its corresponding entry in matrix B. The input matrices should be the same size, and the output will be the same size as well. This is achieved using the `mul()` function:

```
output = A.mul(B);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to see how this answers the question. Why should the assertion fail in the first statement "h*ft"?

Comment: Because as it stands, h*ft is attempting to perform matrix multiplication which, noticing how h and ft are formed, would require src.rows == src.cols.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course. I assumed they were equal. My bad.

Comment: The * operator is not supported in JAVA. You have to use the Core.gemm method.

Comment: This is very helpful! Thanks @Chris for the explanation.