# OpenCV: How do I multiply every value of a Mat by a specified constant?

Tags: java, opencv

I've got a Java program using OpenCV. I have a Mat that's filled with numbers from 0 to 1. I want to convert this into a grayscale image by multiplying every value in the Mat by 255.

How do I do this?

Comment: Hi Sir! Did you solve the problem? I also have the same issue in Java

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the java OpenCV API (I work mainly with c++) but I'll chip in since nobody has answered yet. It looks like [`convertTo(Mat m, int rtype, double alpha)`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#convertTo%28org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int,%20double%29) would do the job. In your case, something like

```
 yourMat.convertTo(output, CV_8UC1, 255);
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Another option instead of your approach is to read the image as Grayscale. Use the flag `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE`

http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/highgui/Highgui.html#imread%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Or if you want to keep your approach. Then you can use matrix multiplication. Already there is a thread for that, which is
[Matrix multiplication in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936099/matrix-multiplication-in-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

I am not using Java but C++, but I assume it should be very similar. In C++ it would be:

```
A *= 255;
```

Since comparison operation create matrix with 0 and 255 you have another option:

```
A = (A>0);
```

Answer (score 0):

[You can use Java's OpenCv Core library](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Core.html#multiply(org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Scalar,org.opencv.core.Mat)):

**public static void multiply​(Mat src1, Scalar src2, Mat dst)**

Example:

```
Mat mat = new Mat(2,2, 1,1,1,1); // 2x2 matrix with all 1's
Scalar scalar = new Scalar(255); // the specific constant
Core.multiply(mat, scalar, mat); // mat values are all 255 now
```