# How could I use opencv to multiply two tensors?

Tags: c++, opencv

Suppose that I have an image `im` and a 3x3 convert matrix, the image is HxWx3, I need to do a multiplication like this:

```
Mat M = Mat::ones(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
M.at<double>(1,1) = 4.0;
Mat res = im * M;
```

The multiplication that I need is like the method of `np.matmul` of the python package of `numpy`. How could I do this please ?

Comment: Your ```im``` is 3 channel but your ```M``` is 1 channel. and what is the width and height of your ```im``` ? Did you already check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936099/matrix-multiplication-in-opencv)

Comment: I do think singe  channel is a problem since `M` is a 3x3 matrix. My image is 1024x2048x3 matrix, and it should output a 1024x2048x3 matrix as result.

Comment: So your im is 1024x2048 and you wanna multiply it with 3x3 ? Is it possible ? By using [np.matmul](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html)?

Comment: Yes, I think so, if the inputs are 1024x2048x3 and 3x4, then `np.matmul` can give me a result of 1024x2048x4.